# Javascript 'this' inside an object literal

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript. I was doing some hands on "object literals". Below is the code i was trying. BodyLoaded is the event handler for onload event of body tag.

//works - getName returns "bingo"

```
function BodyLoaded()
{
    var dog = {

        name: "defaultname",
        getName: function () {
            return name;
        },
        setName: function (n) {
            name = n;
        }
    };

    dog.setName("bingo");
    console.log(dog.getName());
}
```

//works too - getName returns "bingo"

```
function BodyLoaded()
{
    var dog = {

        name: "defaultname",
        getName: function () {
            return this.name;
        },
        setName: function (n) {
            this.name = n;
        }
    };

    dog.setName("bingo");
    console.log(dog.getName());
}
```

//doesnt work - getName returns ""

```
function BodyLoaded()
{
    var dog = {

        name: "defaultname",
        getName: function () {
            return this.name;
        },
        setName: function (n) {
            name = n;
        }
    };

    dog.setName("bingo");
    console.log(dog.getName());
}
```

The above code returns expected result when calling getName ("bingo"). But if I return this.name in the getName  function, it returns and empty string. The strange part is, if i use this.name in both the functions (setName and getName) the code works fine and returns the expected value("bingo"). Trying to understand this behavior.

Comment: I don't see the issue with the empty string, but `this` refers to the parent object.

Comment: Off topic but avoid using body-onload, use eventlistener `loaded` on `window` instead.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [Javascript: Do I need to put this.var for every variable in an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418669/javascript-do-i-need-to-put-this-var-for-every-variable-in-an-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you return `name` from the method, it actually returns the `window.name` because there is not context involved.

When you call `this.name`, `this` points to the `dog` object which has a `name` property so it returns that.

Comment: The question is not about what this is pointing to. Question is why if use this.name or name in both the setName and getName function i get expected result(Bingo). But when i use this.name in getName and simply name in setName it returns an empty string.

Comment: because when you use only `name` it points to `window.name` and `this.name` it points to `dog.name`

Comment: please look at the first code. I am using only name in that case. why does name in that case doesnt point to window?

Comment: @user1360433 can you check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7a66H/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify `this` when setting the `name` value the actual variable that gets set will be `window.name`. But when you use `this.name` the actual value that gets set will be `dog.name`. Just modify the code as given below and see.

```
function BodyLoaded()
{

    var dog = {

    name: "defaultname",
    getName: function () {
        return this.name;
    },
    setName: function (n) {
        this.name = n;
    }
};

dog.setName("bingo");
console.log(dog.getName());
```

}

But as per your given code I couldn't understand the reason for getting an empty string. If should actually output value `defaultname`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Dog() {
    var self = this;

    this.name = "defaultname";
    this.getName = function () {
        return this.name;
        // same as
        // return self.name
    }
}
var myDog = new Dog();
myDog.getName(); // defaultname
```