# maintaining scope inside a jquery ui widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-widget-factory, jquery-ui-widget

I am having a problem with loosing scope inside a [widget](http://jqueryui.com/widget/). Inside _initialize, `this.options` does not work, and neither does `that.options`. How can I access the scope of the widget from this method?

```
$.widget("myproj.map", {
        options: {
            centerLat: 51.511214,
            centerLong: -0.119824,
        },

        // the constructor
        _create: function () {
            var that = this;
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', this._initialize);
        },
        _initialize: function () {

            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(that.options.centerLat, that.options.centerLong),
                zoom: 11,
            };
```

To clarify

```
$.widget("myproj.map", {
        options: {
            centerLat: 51.511214,
            centerLong: -0.119824,
        },

        // the constructor
        _create: function () {
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', this._initialize);
        },
        _initialize: function () {
            console.log(this);
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(this.options.centerLat, this.options.centerLong),
                zoom: 11
            }; ...code omitted
```

does not work, when I console.log this in _initialize I get

```
Window {top: Window, window: Window, location: Location, external: Object, chrome: Object…}
```

Comment: you have commas all over the place... unended `};`, `}` etc...

Comment: I think he just omitted the closing of _initialize and widget , missing: `} });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`google.maps.event.addDomListener` changes what `this` refers to. you can change it back by calling the [bind mehtod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/bind-method-of-javascript)

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', this._initialize.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: this answer does address rebinding caused by the event handler

`var that` is scoped inside the `_create` function, you should be able to access `this` [from within initialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal).

```
new google.maps.LatLng(this.options.centerLat, this.options.centerLong)
```

check out this [similar question about "this"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251518/javascript-this-inside-an-object-literal)

Comment: I only added in the 'that' variable as I was loosing scope going into the initialize function from the google.maps.event listener

Comment: ahh i see. added a new answer